# How to enable keep-alive in HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dnx50

HttpClient class with in .NET core is not using keep-alives. It is re-connecting and re-authenticating to server on each request. This can be especially slow with [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) authentication that requires multiple round-trips.

I'm passing new HttpClientHandler() to HttpClient constructor.

In .NET 4, I could use WebRequestHandler that has keep-alive capabilities, but this class seems to be missing in .NET Core.

Is there a way to enable keep-alives for HttpClient in .NET Core?

Comment: Are you seeing an explicit header to turn keep-alive off? It is the default in HTTP 1.1

Comment: I intercept traffic using Fiddler proxy and see that for each request new connection is established and authentication handshake is repeated. There are also no keep-alive headers sent to server.  For older .Net applications based on .Net 4.5, I can see that there is a single established connection that is re-used.

Comment: NTLM does not allow connection re-use by default. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx